# PHP alters values fetched from SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I can't wrap my head around this one.. I have a Float type value stored in my Sql Server database - Let's say that this value is 4.2. I'm querying the database using the PHP 'odbc_exec' and 'odbc_fetch_array' functions. When I display the value on my page it is now 4.2000000000000002. It's as simple as that.. What could be causing this?? A select statement in the database management studio shows a different number than PHP.

I should note that when I step through the PHP code using netbeans the value is altered from the moment it is fetched so this has nothing to do with the way i'm printing this to the page.

Please help!

Thank You

Comment: you might want to poste the code that displays the value, the exact type of your columns values, and the options that create the database connection object. there are a few different places where such a thing could happen

Comment: There's really not much to post as far as displaying the value goes because, as I've stated, this problem occurs before I display All that I am doing is: $result = odbc_exec($link, $query); then $rowresult = odbc_fetch_array($result) .... The column is of type 'float' and connection string is "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};<credentials>

Comment: well then, it appears the screen is actually displaying the right value. the representation of 4.2 is not actually 4.2. your database management studio may be rounding it, but 4.2000000000000002 is much closer to a float then 4.2

Comment: Am I understanding floats wrong? should I be using a different datatype to have the exact decimal value that i need?

Comment: possibly. if you intend on making computations on those values you should definitely consider using a decimal type (I don't exactly know sql server, but most flavor of sql have such a type); that is, a type that will store exactly the number of digits you say before and after the point, without the floating point arithmetics uncertainty